# How to solve time limit exceeded problem?

Tags: c

I have to make a hollow diamond pattern with stars filling everything. For an input of N, it is supposed to print a 2*N size grid with hollow diamond. For the following code, I am getting time limit exceeded. What needs to be done?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int row,col,space,n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(row=1;row<=n;row++)
    {
        for(col=n;col>=row;col--)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        for(space=2;space<(2*row)-1;space++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        if (row==1)
        printf("\b");
        for(col=n;col>=row;row--)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
   
    for(row=n-1;row>=1;row--)
        {
            for(col=n;col>=row;col--)
            {
                printf("*");
            }
            for(space=1;space<=(2*row)-1;space++)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            if (row==1)
            printf("\b");
            for(col=n;col>=row;row--)
            {
            printf("*");
            }
        printf("\n");
        }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not just submit your code to an online judge. Run it yourself to see if it works. A simple experiment would have reveal this program prints far more output than it should. Then you should have used a debugger or modified your program to probe its behavior, to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is getting into infinite loop. There are two obvious flaws in your code. You have an outer loop - `for(row=1;row<=n;row++)` and then you are changing the row variable in one of the inner loops -

```
for(col=n;col>=row;row--)
```

`col` for sure is greater than `row` and you keep on decrementing row which means the `col>=row` condition always evaluates to True.This would make your code go into infinite loop. Just change it to - `for(col=n;col>=row;col--)` which would prevent your program from going into infinite loop.

There's also some logic error in the second half of diamond print pattern. Your first loop works fine, but your code produces slight misaligned results in the lower one due to more space.

I have corrected the spaces printed in the lower half which would give you the correct results -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int row,col,space,n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(row=1;row<=n;row++)
    {
        for(col=n;col>=row;col--)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        for(space=2;space<(2*row)-1;space++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        if (row==1)
        printf("\b");
        for(col=n;col>=row;col--)  // <-- Changed here from row--, to col--
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
   
    for(row=n-1;row>=1;row--)
        {
            for(col=n;col>=row;col--)
            {
                printf("*");
            }
            // Note the changes below in the number of spaces printed
            for(space=1;space<(2*(row-1));space++)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            if (row==1)
            printf("\b");
            for(col=n;col>=row;col--)  // <-- Changed here from row--, to col--
            {
            printf("*");
            }
        printf("\n");
        }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This one would print the correct diamond pattern

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
for(col=n;col>=row;row--)
{
    printf("*");
}
```

`col` starts at `n`, which is necessarily greater than or equal to `row` due to prior code, so `col>=row` is true. Subsequently, this loop decrements `row` with `row--`. This causes `row` to get smaller, so `col>=row` remains true, and the loop continues executing.

This continues until `row--` causes an overflow (the value goes outside the range that `int` can represent), at which point the behavior is not defined by the C standard.